# Setting up Proftpd with Google Compute Engine Using Passive Ports?

Tags: google-compute-engine, proftpd

So I am a little confused. 
We have a bunch of soil moisture stations that submit data to our server via ftp.  We can not change this to sftp, or ftps, good old plain ftp :/

I have setup a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.
I have also installed proftpd and I can successfully connect to the server via FileZilla under both passive and active modes.
I have enabled port 21 and a range for passive ports (49152-65534) that are set in the config of proftpd, as well as enabling these in Google VPC Firewall rules.

All seems well.. accept when a station attempts to connect to the server.
I get the note stating that a station has connected, but then it fails when attempting to run in passive mode.
The fail note is 'Hostname was not found'

I have tried turning off `UseReverseDNS` but this seems to do nothing what so ever.

I should also note that we have Proftpd setup and working on an older VPS setup outside of GCP.  That is working with no issues, with the same config.

Here is the full log from the station that is attempting to connect

```
Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host xx.xx.xx.xx
Connected to xx.xx.xx.xx (xx.xx.xx.xx) port 21 (#0)
Request has same path as previous transfer
PASV^M
Connect data stream passively
ftp_perform ends with SECONDARY: 0
227 Entering Passive Mode (10,152,0,20,232,150).^M
Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
  Trying 10.152.0.20...
Connecting to 10.152.0.20 (xx.xx.xx.xx) port 59542
```

And then the logs from the server running proftpd

```
[05/Jun/2019:06:07:17 +0000] "PASS (hidden)" 230 -
[05/Jun/2019:06:07:17 +0000] "PWD" 257 -
[05/Jun/2019:06:07:17 +0000] "CWD incoming" 250 -
[05/Jun/2019:06:07:17 +0000] "PASV" 227 -
```

You can see that it is connecting and able to change into the correct directory, but that is when it fails.

Has anyone come across this or something similar to this before?
I am wondering if it has to do with the way Google sets the hostname.

Edit: Note re other vps, port ranges

Comment: `10.0.0.0` is a private network; you cannot use that IP for passive mode... just don't send `PASV`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler, unfortunately, it has to run as passive we don't have control over that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so to answer this question if anyone does come across it.

In `proftpd.conf` I uncommented `MasqueradeAddress` and set the IP address to match the server's static IP address; IE `MasqueradeAddress    xx.xx.xx.xx` where `xx.xx.xx.xx` is the static IP of the given server.

I also created my own config and placed this in `conf.d` with the following

```
UseReverseDNS off
IdentLookups off
```

Without disabling the `UseReverseDNS` and `IndentLookups` the connection was timing out and the stations where not able to upload.

More information if you are interested

- [MasqueradeAddress](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/NAT.html)
- [UseReverseDNS](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/DNS.html)
- [IdentLookups](https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/speed-up-proftpd-login-for-all-users.583/)

Answer (score 0):

During the Passive mode connection establishment, the port 21 will be used by the client to initiate the connection. After that a random port from a range will be used by the client, and will be used by the server to send the response.
You can actually see in the client log that is trying to connect to the port 59542, and its probably being dropped by the server.
I suggest to check if you have a particular firewall rule in GCP to open the port range based on the client configuration. You can check this information here: https://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html
Also I suggest to check the internal system firewall rules.

Comment: Lozano, thanks for the link.  That all makes sense.  I actually have ports 49152-65534 open in both the Proftpd settings and GCP firewall settings.  So with that I assumed it should work.  I should also mention that we have Proftpd working on another VPS that is not hosted with Google, and that is working no problems

Comment: @MatthiasLaw is that `10.x` coming from the device? because GCP internal network also has `10.x` ...some FTP clients also permit to enter an external IP address as the passive mode IP address (eg. when the auto-detection picks the wrong interface).

Comment: @MartinZeitler that was being generated by Proftpd from what I can see, I used the `MasqueradeAddress` config option to set that to the IP of the server and it worked, thanks for your help here